# Minimal gcc installation in separate folder on os x

Tags: macos, gcc, compiler-construction

Is this possible to install pure `gcc` with header files on os x lion in a separate folder?

That way I could keep my OS clean and have all of my development tools in one place.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. You can install the Xcode Command Line Tools without Xcode. Or you can install Xcode without the Command Line Tools. Or you can install a non-Apple gcc to somewhere like /usr/local—Homebrew or MacPorts will do this for you. Is one of those what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to keep my os clean and "vanilla". That's why I don't want to install Command Line Tools ( it contains a lot of compilers and tools which I won't be using ). I'm asking if I could get minimal gcc installation running from custom location ( not eg. /usr/bin )

Comment: Well, I think Xcode is far more "vanilla" than any custom install you might do. But I'll write up an answer explaining how to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a very bad idea. It's going to be hard to do, many open source packages that use autoconf will get highly confused, you won't be able to use Homebrew/MacPorts/Fink, etc. And the end result will hardly be "vanilla"; it will be different from every other Mac development system in the world, and much harder to restore from scratch if you ever need to. Also, if you build stock gcc, rather than Apple-patched gcc, you won't have any of the Apple extensions (e.g., the `-arch` flag).

You can get around some of these problems by copying at least one of the Xcode SDKs somewhere on your system, and just setting up your environment to always use that SDK. But some of them, there's just no way around. (For example, many configure scripts will be un-confused if you do that, but obviously that won't fix the -arch flag.)

So, I would strongly suggest installing Xcode, or at least installing the standalone Xcode Command Line Tools package (available from developer.apple.com), instead.

But what you want to do is doable.

First, there are some binary builds of gcc around, such as at [these](http://hpc.sourceforge.net/). That's probably the easiest way to go. And, once you've got a compiler, if it's not the one you want, you can always use it to compile the one you actually do want.

Alternatively, you can just install Command Line Tools, use that to build the gcc you want, then uninstall Command Line Tools.

Or you can install Command Line Tools on another Mac, use that to build gcc, and copy it over. (You can probably even do the build with Homebrew, and just copy over the /usr/local/Cellar/gcc and set up the symlinks.)

If you really like pain, you can cross-compile gcc from a totally different platform.